# Jupyter Labs: hide code cells and run all cells on start

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to convert my Jupyter Labs notebook to a read only copy where the Python code is hidden (except any input fields) and all cells are ran upon loading the notebook. What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: You can look at [jupyter nbextensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions), they maybe relevant.

Comment: "Due to major differences between the Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab, the extensions in this repository will not work in JupyterLab." would that not apply then?

Comment: Sorry read your question too quickly, I'm sure there are some [jupyterLab extensions](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html) which will be useful!